# Is the line “Bush never quit figured out how to deal with him, and finished well behind him“grammatically right?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

There was the following passage in Time magazine’s (February 20) article titled, “Watch Jeb Bush’s saddest campaign moments”:

> Jeb Bush’s campaign has fallen short of expectations. At one time the
>   Republican front-runner with substantial money behind his campaign’s
>   super PAC, the former Florida Governor was the man to beat. Then,
>   billionaire Donald Trump emerged as a more serious contender than his
>   veteran team had anticipated. **Bush never quit figured out how to deal
>   with him,** and finished well behind him Saturday in South Carolina. It
>   was the latest example of Bush winding up with disappointing results
>   despite earnest efforts.-
>
> http://time.com/4231020/jeb-bush-please-clap-saddest-moments-south-carolina/?xid=homepage

I copy-and-pasted the above quote from the text, but I don’t understand what the line, “Bush **never quit figured out** how to deal with him,” mean. Does it mean ”Bush never has quitted to figure out how to deal with Trump? Is it due to the lack of my understanding, or a simple typo?

Comment: I'm sure it's a typo for "Bush never quite figured out."

Comment: The most vexing typos are the ones that make another word. Had a trailing _e_ been left off a word like _equate_, the copy editor would have had the benefit of a red squiggly line under _equat_. But in cases where the dropped _e_ forms another word (like _shine_ and _shin_, or, in this case, _quite_ and _quit_), it's harder to catch the error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's almost certainly merely a typo that is causing the problem.

Comment: ＠Edwin Ashworth. I don't mind if one of 952 questions I’ve posted be closed. It doesn't make a dint. But as you acknowledge that “a typo caused the problem,” and JR pointed out that “the most vexing typos are the ones that make another word,” this is clearly a problematic passage. I could have the option of not asking the question, and putting it in the air, unsolved in my mind. But remember this site is not exclusive to native English speakers who can tell whether it’s typo or not instinctively and automatically.

Comment: Cont. I think there should be smidgen of allowance or deliberation in branding an on-topic and off-topic question before wielding close / down vote with a portion of non-native users in your mind.

Comment: I voted to close, too, with the thought that future site visitors who search on the word _quit_ may still find this question, even though it is closed. There is certainly nothing wrong with asking the question, since the wording in question might have turned out to be some strange idiomatic form in English—but once it appears that _quit_ is only a typo, I think we don't gain by leaving it open rather than closing it.

Comment: Yoichi Oishi San, I don't think closing a question means this community doesn't like your question and furthermore, the question might not generate more answers other than the below answer. I thought about voting to reopen it, but I decided not to. I am a big fan of your questions and please don't take it personally. Thanks.

Comment: @Rathony. Thank you for your attention and caring words. I don't take it personally, but still feel a kinda cultural gap from those who take typos for granted, because a typo in major journal is unusual and shameful in our country, where it takes months or a year for you to locate any single typo in the leading newspapers and magazines like the Asahi, the Yomiuri and Bungeishunju.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is mistyped and the writer meant "Bush never quite figured out how to deal with him". This would mean Bush did not know how to deal with him.
If they had meant quitting, the wording may have been something like "Bush never quit figuring out how to deal with him" or "quit trying to figure out".

Comment: Hello, Pablo. This would not generally be considered a suitable question to give an 'answer' to on ELU. Note deadrat's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Edwin. Since I am new to this site (actually new to stack exchange) I did not know.

Comment: It would be good to read the information at the Help Center, if you haven't done so, and read through the main  reasons why quite a few questions are  closed.

Comment: Actually I did read lots of information there and found about good and bad questions... Did not find a hint that it was good not to answer questions ever, if the question was not good.